# Can you run console jobs from yii2-basic?

Tags: yii, yii2

I am aware that Yii2-advanced has the ability to run console jobs (php yii controllername) but I was wondering if the basic app has the same ability? I notice a console.php file in the config folder, but cannot seem to get the jobs to run.

If it is possible, can someone give an example - where does the controller go (since I put it in controllers, but I get the message 'Error: Unknown command test' when trying php yii test)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you really meant console commands, not console jobs. I have a jobs directory that holds all the background jobs implemented using ResQue and it has a different syntax to run them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the same functionality exists in the basic template too.

However, it's organized a bit differently.

By default the console controllers are located in **commands** folder (you can change that by editing this setting: `'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands'`).

Configuration is managed through `config/console.php` that you mentioned.

As for example you can take a look at [HelloController](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/commands/HelloController.php) which comes with template by default.

You can find more info in according official docs [section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html).

As for you error, accurately check controller name and its action names, most likely the problem is there.

**Update:** Make sure you have at least one action in this controller, otherwise the same error ("Unknown command") will appear.

You can list all available commands with `php yii` command.

Comment: The docs are useless. They don't mention `commands/` path or `controllerNamespace` at all.