# Yii2 - RBAC rule to allow/view own data

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-rbac

I have installed `yii2mod/yii2-rbac` from this url - https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-rbac in yii2-basic.

everything is working fine except using/allowing owner data.

from this link:https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization
I have created a folder in root `rbac` and file `AuthorRule.php` and code:

```
namespace app\rbac;

use yii\rbac\Rule;

//use app\models\Post;

/**
 * Checks if authorID matches user passed via params
 */
class AuthorRule extends Rule
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = 'isAuthor';

    /**
     * @param string|int $user the user ID.
     * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
     * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
     * @return bool a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
     */
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        return isset($params['post']) ? $params['post']->createdBy == $user : false;
    }
}
```

but when I try to add the rule in permission(either `AuthorRule` or `isAuthor` under permission I created updateOwnRecord, I am getting the error, the rule doesn't exist.

What I am missing here?

Comment: have you modified your configs, like it were said? after you installed yii2-rbac, have you run migrations?

Comment: have you created that schema and added rules and roles ?

Comment: Hi Omer - yes I have created the schema, roles and it is working fine except as I said I am not able to make it work for view/update own records. I think after adding rbac folder in site root, I need to add somewhere in config to include the rbac folder like we do for components and modules.

Comment: Hi Omer - I have also tried like - created a folder `myweb` in vendors and added `rbac/AuthorRule.php` with the same contents. but still when I tried to add `AuthorRule` in permission, it is not picking it.

Comment: are you trying to control that a user should be able to delete its own records only? you might have to create a **`Rule`** class that extends `yii\rbac\Rule`, see this [article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-rules) that might help you out, go one and follow the instructions and i you get stuck update with the new info in your question

Comment: Hi Omer - I have pasted exactly that rule you are referring to in my question. only thing I am missing is, where and how I extend it. I mean where I should place that rule? I tried placing that by creating a folder in vendor `myweb` and in that folder `rbac` and file `AuthorRule.php`. but looks like it is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: earlier I tried the same by creating folder `rbac` in site root.

Comment: OOPS! i totaly overlooked it where is the code for adding the rule ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198967/discussion-between-joshi-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: were you able to solve the problem or still stucked up somewhere

Comment: can you mark the answer as correct if it worked for you

Comment: Hi Omer. - It did helped, but what worked for me is completely different than your answer. just stuck-up in some work, I will post the answer with step by step.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I try to add the rule in permission(either AuthorRule or
> isAuthor under permission I created updateOwnRecord, I am getting the
> error, the rule doesn't exist

Not sure where you are getting the error you mentioned as there is no relevant code, but looking at your details i recon you havent understood the process correctly.

- Create a permission `updatePost` in the `auth_item` .
- Add `AuthorRule` class's serialized instance to `auth_rule` table.
- Create a new permission `updateOwnPost`and specify the rule name i.e `isAuthor`.
- Add the permission `updatePost` as a child to `UpdateOwnPost` in the `auth_item_child` table.

  - the `isAuthor` will be the name of the rule that you will supply to the `updateOwnPost` permission's `rule_name` column.
- Add the `updatePost` as a child of the `role` you want to use the rule for, like `user` or anyother you have created for the standard user role.

See the below code you can run it once via any temporary action for now, we will discuss it's place later in the answer below.

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
$updatePost = $auth->getPermission('updatePost');

//change it to whichever role you want to assign it like `user` `admin` or any other role
$role = $auth->getRole('user');

// add the rule
$rule = new \app\rbac\AuthorRule;
$auth->add($rule);

// add the "updateOwnPost" permission and associate the rule with it.
$updateOwnPost = $auth->createPermission('updateOwnPost');
$updateOwnPost->description = 'Update own post';
$updateOwnPost->ruleName = $rule->name;
$auth->add($updateOwnPost);

// "updateOwnPost" will be used from "updatePost"
$auth->addChild($updateOwnPost, $updatePost);

// allow "author" to update their own posts
$auth->addChild($role, $updateOwnPost);
```

Now if all goes well and you can add a rule by running the code above

> Remember You need to check the `updatePost` rule in the check `Yii::$app->user->can()` **and not `updateOwnPost`** and pass the `Post` model instance along as the second parameter

Like this

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('updatePost', ['post' => $post])) {
    // update post
}
```

---

#### About The code Placement in the current application

If you want to have a separate interface where you can add create all with a form then you can follow `dektrium-rbac` code available already where it provides complete crud that you can use according to your own requirements.

For the reference see below

- [Add Rule Form](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac/blob/master/views/rule/_form.php)
- [RuleController::actionCreate](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac/blob/master/controllers/RuleController.php#L83)
- [RuleModel::create()](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac/blob/master/models/Rule.php#L122)

***Note: if you have a lot of controllers and you want to associate this rule with every update action inside the controllers (Given that all the associated models have the `created_by` field) then you might go for the `console\Controller` and run such processes via console, so that every new `controller/update` can be associated with the rule repeating the above process inside a loop. For the console controller usage in basic-app see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090479/can-you-run-console-jobs-from-yii2-basic)***

Comment: Thanks Omer - I will try to use as per your suggestion. will accept later. already upvoted.

Comment: no issue @Joshi , take your time, the first priority is that the solution should work for you correctly.