# create rule class in dektrium module rbac in basic project yii2

Tags: yii2, rules, rbac

I  installed dektrium\user and dektrium\rbac\ modules for manage user and access control.Related tables and files installed completely and i can see several tabs in /user/admin path ( Users, Roles, Permissions, Rules, Create ) for work with modules.I can manage users perfectly(create user, reset password, edit,..). buy I can not create a rule. 
I created a class in app\rbac\rules folder named AuthorRule :

```
<?php 
namespace app\rbac\rules;

use yii\rbac\Rule;
use app\models\News;

/**
 * Checks if authorID matches user passed via params
 */
class AuthorRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isAuthor';

    /**
     * @param string|int $user the user ID.
     * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
     * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
     * @return bool a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
     */
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        return isset($params['news']) ? $params['news']->createdBy == $user : false;
    }
}
```

(I created news class with model,controler,views)
but when I entered name and class rule in  my modules. Neither the data is logged nor the error message. I can't add the rest of the sections until I get into the rule.

[image]

Comment: does it save the rule with the above details?, if yes then you need to assign the rule to the user by creating a new permission and selecting the above created rule in the form. See the create new persmission form and you will understand

Comment: to understand the complete process see the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778924/yii2-rbac-rule-to-allow-view-own-data/57796394#57796394) where the process is done manually without using the above form

Comment: I know I should to assign, but I  must be made a rule that I can not do. it dose not save rule.

Comment: what error does it throw ?

Comment: I cannot create any rule and  I have not any message in view. I have  the second picture when I click "save" Button. I searched a lot. But I couldn't find a solution  muhammad can you help me if you want please send mail for me : masoudy.maryam@gmail.com .Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 0):

I certainly hope the OP has solved their problem by now, but other people might encounter it.

First a remark: as described, the *Save* fails silently. This is because the form is submitted with Ajax (XHR). The error can be seen in the browser console.

This is the relevant part of the error message:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 8

Due to the architecture of Yii 2, the actual regexp is a little tricky to find. It is in the model for Rules in yii2-rbac *vendor/dektrium/yii2-rbac/models/Rule.php*, line 86.

The original regexp is `/^[\w][\w-.:]+[\w]$/`

PHP 7.3 uses the PCRE2 library instead of the original PCRE, and the pattern above is wrong. The dash (-) needs to be escaped.

The full line should now be:

```
['name', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[\w][\w\-.:]+[\w]$/'],
```

As the yii2-rbac package is abandoned, you can just modify the file. A more robust solution would be to override the Class.